# Proof that a blade has no scalar part from Eric Chisolm's set of axioms for geometric algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, clifford-algebras

In [Eric Chisolm's essay on geometric algebra](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1205.5935.pdf), the author asserts in page 12 that a 2-blade, by definition the product of two orthogonal vectors (vectors $u$ and $v$ for which $uv+vu=0$), can't have a scalar part, because "*it anticommutes with both u and v, which means that it can’t have a scalar part, because that part would have commuted with all vectors.*"

I'm not following. What does it mean for something to anticommute with "both" something and something? I understand that the geometric product of orthogonal vectors is an anticommutative operation, but I don't understand what it means for it to anticommute with both terms.

This should follow from the five preceding axioms he set forth:

Axiom 1. $G$ is a ring with unit. The additive identity is called $0$ and the multiplicative identity is called $1$.

Axiom 2. $G$ contains a field $G_0$ of characteristic zero which includes $0$ and $1$.

Axiom 3. $G$ contains a subset $G_1$ closed under addition, and $λ ∈ G_0, v ∈ G_1$ implies $λv = vλ ∈ G_1$.

Axiom 4. The square of every vector is a scalar.

Axiom 5. The inner product is nondegenerate.

This seems like that should be a simple consequence of these axioms and the definitions, but I can't see why $uv$ couldn't just have a scalar part $\mu$, and $vu$ have a scalar part $-\mu$.

Comment: I think he means that neither $u$ nor $v$ can be scalar because that would violate anticommutativity. Right above that on (29) he says that $\lambda A=A\lambda$ which is what makes me believe this. He is not saying we can't have $\mu A\lambda B=\mu\lambda AB$.

Comment: @JohnDouma I don't believe he means that, as $u$ and $v$ are by hypothesis both 1-vectors, so pure vectors, with no scalar part, right off the bat. The sentence that follows the one I quoted makes it clearer in my view that he is in fact speaking of blades: "*In fact, for this same reason no even blade can have a scalar part; and no odd blade can either, as long as
there’s another vector orthogonal to all the factors in the blade.*" I have no issue with $μAλB=μλAB$.

Comment: I don't see anything in that section about one vectors. What do you think he means by a scalar part? He gives the example of $\langle\lambda A\rangle_r$ in c) below axiom 6 so he seems to allow scalar multiples of r-vectors.

Comment: @JohnDouma He gives sensible definitions of scalars and vectors (1-vectors) in the explanatory texts that follow axioms 2 and 3, on page 11, where he establishes the convention that *"A member of G1 is called a 1-vector, a homogeneous multivector of grade 1, or just a vector. Vectors are denoted by lower case Roman letters (a, b, u, v, etc.). *" On axiom 4 he goes on to derive results for 1-vectors $u$ and $v$, two symbols he recurrently uses to refer to 1-vectors. Axiom 5 defines blades as products of orthogonal vectors (page 12). I think what he means as the scalar part of $uv$ is $⟨uv⟩_0$.

Answer (score 1):

He's saying that $uv$ anticommutes with $u$ and also anticommutes with $v$. His argument is then something like: suppose $uv = \lambda + x$ where $\lambda \in \mathcal G_0$ and $x \not\in\mathcal G_0$. Then
$$
  -\lambda u + xu = -(\lambda + x)u = u(\lambda + x) = \lambda u + ux
$$
and he is then somehow concluding that $\lambda = 0$. Whether or not we conclude *anything* is highly non-obvious to me, and certainly shouldn't be left as a passing remark.

Axiom 6 is then introduced and renders this consideration moot, since it just declares the notion of scalar part as the projection onto $\mathcal G_0$ and declares this as linearly independent from $\mathcal G_2$.

Axiom 6 is "morally" wrong. He says, "If $\mathcal G_0 = \mathcal G_1$ then, $\mathcal G = \mathcal G_1$." In the case of a one-dimensional vector space, i.e. $\mathcal G_1 = \mathbb R$, then a geometric algebra should have $\mathcal G = \mathbb R\oplus\mathbb R$: we still have a scalar part and a vector part, it just turns out that all vectors are multiples of each other. In any case, equating both copies of $\mathbb R$ here would be a type error since the first is supposed to be a set of scalars and the second a set of vectors.

If we interpret the author as not making such a type error, then it would seem that he is trying to refer to the zero-dimensional case. But in this case we should have $\mathcal G = \mathcal G_0 \ne \{0\}$ with the last inequality from Axiom 2, while it ought to be that $\mathcal G_1 = \{0\}$ if this set is to be interpreted as the set of vectors. But it is true that if $\mathcal G = \mathbb R$ then $\mathcal G_1 = \mathcal G_0 = \mathbb R$ models these axioms, hence why Axiom 6 is only "morally" wrong.

---

The above "argument" for $uv$ not having a "scalar part" as well as the above confusion that Axiom 6 brings does not instill confidence in me. My personal recommendation for an introduction to geometric algebra is either *Geometric Algebra for Physicists* by Chris Doran and Anthony Lasenby or *Clifford Algebras and Spinors* by Pertti Lounesto. I want to explicitly point out Section 14 of Lounesto which discusses different ways to define Clifford algebras, in particular what is needed if the algebra is to be declared as generated by vectors.

Comment: Axiom 2 is correct. If the vector space is $\{0\}$, the Clifford algebra is $\mathbb R$. (In particular, the dimensions are correct, as $2^0=1$.)

Comment: @mr_e_man You're right morally, but in this particular case we don't "need" to consider unital algebras (and forgetting the identity element is where I went wrong here). If our universal property is for non-unital associative algebras $A$ where $f : \{0\} \to A$ such that $f(0) = 0$ extends uniquely to a homomorphism $f' : \mathcal G \to A$, then $\mathcal G = \{0\}$ otherwise you have the choice between $f'(x) = 0$ and $f'(x) = x$ and so violate uniqueness. Of course this is silly because for non-trivial quadratic forms we use the identity element of an algebra in the universal property.

Comment: I've removed the remark about Axiom 2, and Axiom 6 is also not technically wrong so I've modified that section as well.